# primitive of the reciprocal of the derivative of a reciprocal function

Tags: calculus

I'm wondering whether we can explicitly solve for a function $g(x)$ from a given function $f(x)$ such that 
$g'(x)=1/((\frac{1}{f(x)})')$.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know quite what you're trying to ask, but if I can correctly parse your equation, the following observation may help.

$$
g^{\prime}(x) = 1/ \left( d \left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right) / d x\right) = \frac{d x}{d\left( \frac{1}{f(x)} \right)} = \frac{f^2(x)d x}{- f^{\prime}(x)}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I mean that whether we can solve for $g$ using a simple transformation of $f$, for instance if $g=log(1/f)$, then $g'=f(1/f)'$, something like that.

Comment: You wrote on the left of the equality the derivative using a prime, but on the right you used $d/dx$... That does not help :-) Your question seems to be «given $f$, can we find $g$ such that $g'=1/((1/f)')$?»

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez♦ that's right!

Comment: @mlg4080, you did something weird with the differentials there...

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez♦ thank you for your comment, I though what mlg4080 did was correct, although that doesn't answer my question, could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: The last expression in his chain of equalities has a $dx$ which was probably not intended. Going from his second expression to the third is somewhat dubious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=xe^x-e^x$. Then the derivative of $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is $\frac{xe^x}{(xe^x-e^x)^2}$. The reciprocal of this is 
$\frac{e^x(x-1)^2}{x}$, which is 
$$xe^x-2e^x+\frac{e^x}{x}.$$
The first two parts have antiderivatives expressible in terms of elementary functions, while the last part does not. So the reciprocal of $\left(\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)'$ does not have an antiderivative expressible in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: I wonder, how did you come up with this counter example.

Comment: Fooled around a bit. Lots of stuff will work, in the sense that the reciprocal of $(1/f(x))'$ has an integral that is not expressible in terms of elementary functions. The problem is to find an example for which I know there is a *proof* of non-expressibility.

Comment: Wow. Can you show me that proof? (at least a link)

Comment: I don't remember where I saw the details of the Risch Algorithm applied to the exponential integral. A number of the standard "big" programs such as Maple implement large parts of the Risch algorithm.

Comment: Thank you. First time I heard that name. I'l try on that.

Comment: You are welcome. I mentioned the Risch Algorithm because it is something one can search on.